# how to check current running activity on screen

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

When I press the "handsfree" button, the `MediaButtonIntentReceiver` code is called and `Main` activity opens on the screen, and a `Toast` shows up.

Every time I press the button, this happens, but I want it to only happen the first time. The second time I press the button, I want to only show the toast, because the activity is already opened.

---

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity
{
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private ComponentName mAudioReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mAudioReceiver =
                new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class.getName());
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mAudioReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        // mAudioManager.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(mAudioReceiver);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

MediaButtonIntentReceiver.java

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Handfree Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Intent i = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
        // abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Toast` into your `Main` activity.

Show the `Toast` only the first time that the activity is displayed.

---

The point is to not use the `MediaButtonIntentReceiver` to check if the `Main` is displayed. Just use the receiver to launch the activity, and place your logic inside the activity.

You could use a `boolean` value to check if it has been displayed yet, which you could set to `false` in the `onPause()` method.

Comment: i get it but i need to do it inside MediabuttonIntentReceiver.

Comment: @user3286595 That is against the design of Android, it will be very difficult, will require a lot of hacks. This method follows the design of Android, and is simple. I recommend you have another look at your reasons. Good luck whichever path you choose, ymmv

Comment: @user3286595 btw whay is the reason you say you "need to do it inside MediabuttonIntentReceiver" - perhaps there is a misunderstanding?